# How to segue to a sub-sub-view while skipping the subview?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I have set up a story board with a navigation controller and sequential sub-views view segues like this: A --> B --> C. A is a delegate of B, B is a delegate of C. A is a list of items, B is for creating/editing an item and C is for setting an item detail that is too complicated to put in B.

Now for creating an item, the value entered in C is a vital starting point, so I want a button on view A that shows view C (without showing view B in between), while view B still acts as a delegate for view C. When The user hits the "Save" button on view C, it should change to view B. But when he hits "Back" in the navigation bar, A should appear again (because it makes no sense to show an empty value in B).

Comment: It's a simple matter to manage `A->B->C->B->A` and `A->C->A` ... but doing that while using `B` as a delegate of `C`? Bad design... think about why you would want a *non-existent view controller* to be an active delegate.

Comment: I'm not sure this is such a great practice of having to go through a view like that when it's not needed. But to answer the question you can try having a button in A that segues to B then on completion segues to C with no animation except from B to C? And then in C hold a variable to know where he came from (whether it's A or B) and then dismiss twice or once accordingly. I'm on at my mac right now so I can't write any code or double check it but I believe the idea is there

Comment: @DonMag @TPN1994 I've edited the question to explain why I want this particular flow. Creating items should be `A->C->B->A`, editing items should be `A->B`, with an optional `B->C->B`.

Comment: @chiborg - I still say you need to re-think your design. User is at `A`... taps **New Item** (for example)... user sees `C` which is **new item detail** view... user taps **Save** and sees `B` which is **Edit Item**???? And has a **Back** button on the Nav Bar which doesn't take him *back to `C`* but instead takes him to `A`??? Sounds like confusing UX, *plus* awkward and difficult to code.